# How to Replace null value with other not null value same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database:

```
 __ __column1_______column2 
 |1st,hanoi,vietnam |  1  |
 |null              |  2  |
 |null              |  3  |
 |null              |  4  |
 |null              |  5  |
 |2st,hanoi,vietnam |  1  |
 |null              |  2  |
 |null              |  3  |
 |null              |  4  |
 |null              |  5  |
```

And I want this---->

```
     __ __column1______column2 
     |1st,hanoi,vietnam|  1  |
     |1st,hanoi,vietnam|  2  |
     |1st,hanoi,vietnam|  3  |
     |1st,hanoi,vietnam|  4  |
     |1st,hanoi,vietnam|  5  |
     |2st,hanoi,vietnam|  1  |
     |2st,hanoi,vietnam|  2  |
     |2st,hanoi,vietnam|  3  |
     |2st,hanoi,vietnam|  4  |
     |2st,hanoi,vietnam|  5  |
```

I want to copy data from row 1 column1 to row 3,4,5; copy row 1 to row 2,3,4,5 below, column 2 is a `Dense_rank`. I tried

```
select case when column2< 6 then String_agg(column1,',')
union
select case when column2< 6 then String_agg(column1,',')
```

but it doesn't work. I used `isnull(column1, (select top 1 [column1]))` but it doesn't work

Comment: sorry , i editted, the value row 1 can be change, it is not hard fixed

Comment: is there another column that can identify which sets of rows (column2 value 2 to 5) belongs to which row `1st,hanoi,vietnam` or `2st,hanoi,vietnam`?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution thank you

```
isnull(STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), [column1]), ','),(select top 1 STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), [column1]), ',') from  ...))
```

Comment: You can self accept your own answer.